# divide jquery page in half with div

Tags: jquery, css, html, containers

I'm developing a UI for a client and need to add a navbar at the center of the index page for supplying various content. I am using a div class="mymiddle" to create a separation but falls behind all other content. Could 2 completely independent scrollable grids be created separated by a navbar?

CSS

```
.mymiddle {
position:fixed;
overflow:scroll;
display:inline-block;
left:0px;
top:225px;
bottom:0px;
width:640px;
}
```

See link for visual description in more detail of what I'm trying to accomplish.
[Coderunnerlabs visual description](http://www.coderunnerlabs.com/graphic-design-2/ui-coderunnerlabs-example/)

Comment: Can z-index have priority? So if I add z-index to all my css properties I could prioritize from 1 to 3 as 1 being the most top of all layers? I'm still needed to utilize the "mymiddle" as, 1) a footer for the top div and a header for the #2 div. Is this more css?

Comment: z-index only works if i keep position:fixed in the css properties. Also it renders my code disabled because the z-index overlays everything. Is there any other option that can act as 1) a footer for the top div and a header for the #2 div. Should I be editing the css properties for data-role="header" or create a entirely new div for this issue?

Comment: Nice work Moob! I dub thee, css knight, of the coderunnerlabs kingdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not convinced that I fully understand the requirements but you could achieve this appearance if you ditch the fixed positions and use a css-table layout. Each part - `#header`, `#content1`, `#centerNav`, `#content2`, `#footer` - can be described as a table-row where `#header` is at the top and `#footer` at the bottom. The containing 'table' is told to be 100% of the available height and width and the two scrollable areas are separated by the `#centerNav`.

[Here's a jsFiddle that better explains the solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/v8E5S/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="layout">
    <div id="header">HEADER and LOGO</div> 
    <div id="container1">
        <div class="scrollable">Container 1...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="centerNav">
        centerNav divide thingummie
    </div> 
    <div id="container2">
        <div class="scrollable">Container 2...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        FOOTER and LOGO
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {height:100%; width:100%; margin:0;}
#layout {display:table; height:100%; width:100%;}
#header, #centerNav, #footer, #container1, #container2 {display:table-row;}
#header, #centerNav, #footer {font-size:20px; background:#333; color:white; height:0; padding:20px;}
#container1 {background:#eeffff; color:#333; height:30%;}
#container2 {background:#ffeeff; color:#333;}
.scrollable {height:100%; overflow:auto;}
```

Comment: are these nested tables? Is this a deprecated approach, meaning if I added javascript or a more powerful script within the grids would this type of layout handle preetee well?

Answer (score 1):

add:

```
z-index: 1; /* or higher */
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index

Comment: I wonder about the `inline-block` definition also.  Z-index is certainly the right call here, but you might also want to make the `display:block` as well.

Comment: @mrrogers than you don't need `display:` at all cause as he says: `I am using a div class="mymiddle"` DIV is `block` by default (if not overwritten)